# Make Android animation smoother when Keyboard is shown during animation

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout like the following:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:animationCache="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
     ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
     ...
    </LinearLayout>
     ...
</LinearLayout>
```

In view_one and view_two are each one `EditTexts` and as soon as one of them gets active, I want to hide the either other view_xxx.
I do so by setting the `VISIBILITY` flag to either GONE or VISIBLE.

As the `LinearLayout` has `android:animateLayoutChanges`set to true, the whole thing is animated. And if i trigger the whole thing not be activating the keyboard but an other button that doesn't bring up the keyboard it runs quite smooth.

But as soon as the keyboard is also shown (at the same time unfortunately) the whole animation gets supper laggy...

Does anybody have any idea on how to make the animation still be fluent?
I already tried the `animationCache` on the surrounding LinearLayout but it didn't change a thing...

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: same problem here sir :